# How do I stop enemy spawning?

Tags: terraria

I made a mushroom biome on the surface and made my house in it. I tried to make sure no zombies or anything could get in by making trapdoor entrances. I dont have a very good weapon (I always give the good weapons I find to the person I play with, since they are yet to even get into hardmode by themselves) and the mushroom zombies and mushi ladybugs are pretty tough to fight. I've tried using peace candles and I'm planning on making a lot of NPC houses underground, but the peace candles dont work very well and it will be a while until I make all the houses. I want my home to be kind of a safe haven without any enemies. Is there any other way I can do it? Or should I just wait until I finish my NPC houses underneath? The picture is my house. [image: This is my house]

Answer (score 8):

If you are willing to cover the entire place with walls, that will stop enemies from spawning.

You can craft up something cheap like stone or normal wood walls and that will do. There are also some walls and wallpapers that look very cool and could make your place look just as cool as it does now. If you don't like the look of the walls I recommend using **glass** or a colored variant, there are also **wallpapers** that look like the sky.

*I personally think* your house there may look great with a rugged bottom of some kind of natural-like material that blends with the mushroom basement-y area, and have that connect up to (not in a straight line - I would suggest it being a rugged line) something like a sky-like wallpaper or glass.

Comment: Most player-placed background wall-type blocks should help with preventing enemy spawns with the exception of dirt walls.

Comment: I'm not sure I want to use walls. I wanted my house to be more like its outdoors, if you know what I mean. If it comes down to it, I may try walls.

Comment: Thanks a lot for more suggestions, but i finally finished all the NPC houses at the bottom and i have realized a lot of a difference, i barely see any monsters in my house now except for during blood moons or solar eclipses but thanks a lot anyway :D

Comment: @BlueTangsRock No, all player-placed walls, including dirt walls, will prevent enemy spawns. The only walls that don’t are naturally placed walls. https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Background_walls